# Burninate the [real] tag

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, burninate-request, tags

I'd suggest that the tag [real](/questions/tagged/real) be burninated. It doesn't have a [summary](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/real/info) yet, and seems to be used in rather different contexts. It doesn't seem to serve much purpose.

Comment: Really? I was really sure that [tag:real] was the really real deal.

Comment: Nuke that tag, but keep the puns

Comment: On a slightly more serious note, I would think that `real` would actually be used for real numbers, I'm quite surprised by what actually is there. Definitely a fan of burnination, and closure of many of those bad questions.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII There are questions like real-time, real-escape, real-device, real-conversion, real space, sql real, ... tagged `real`.  I'm not sure if it helps!

Comment: Things like real-device, real-conversion, and real-escape don't really have much meaning at first glance, do they? All things considered, I don't think trying to split this tag into multiple sub tags makes sense.

Comment: Wouldn't it be enough to only remove the tag from those few question where the OP is asking something about an 'actual' value?

Comment: I didn't hint splitting the tag.  As you mentioned, the only reasonable usage might have been in context of real numbers.  However, that doesn't seem to be the case.  It's probably best to get rid of.

Comment: @rene but that still leaves the tag without a concrete meaning, making it useless for SEO and question discovery, the main purpose of the tags.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII The tag would then be only appropiate for question in respect of real numbers. but we can decide to retag to [tag:floating-point] there is a tag for double as well, should that go as well then?

Comment: I cleaned out all the Qs that had [real]+[time] or meant real-time, cleaned up stuff talking about "real devices" (phones), and removed the tag on a few that had it for no good reason. Should only be Qs left that talk about real numbers in a way or another, not sure what to do with the tag at this point.

Comment: If we want a tag for real numbers, I suggest replacing it with [tag:real-number] or similar, as the name actually describes it then.